# xgboost training fail in sagemaker studio lab

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

i was training a model in sagemaker studiolab but, the training job in aws sagemaker console was running but it throw me this error:

UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job sagemaker-xgboost-2021-12-23-14-59-41-581: Failed. Reason: AlgorithmError: framework error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_trainer.py", line 84, in train
entrypoint()
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/training.py", line 94, in main
train(framework.training_env())
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/training.py", line 90, in train
run_algorithm_mode()
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/training.py", line 68, in run_algorithm_mode
checkpoint_config=checkpoint_config
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/algorithm_mode/train.py", line 139, in sagemaker_train
csv_weights, is_pipe, combine_train_val)
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/algorithm_mode/train.py", line 82, in get_validated_dmatrices
validate_data_file_path(train_path, content_type)
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.

Comment: Hello Matias33,
Are you using SageMaker Studio or SageMaker Studio Lab? Is there a link that you can share your code snippet?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Problem solved by myself, thanks :)
It was a error from my dataset

Comment: How did you solve this problem? I am facing the same problem.